# MySQL автозамена символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, str-replace, urlencode

В скрипте MySQL использует для составления URL страниц их заголовки, в которых попадаются `!?,\` и даже полные веб адреса типа `http://`

Кирилические символы енкодятся, пробелы заменяются на `-`. Но символов много. Есть ли готовый способ, который отслеживает, чтоб не появилось вредных или запрещенных символов в генерируемой строке для URL?

```
while(($cur_str = fgets($file)) !== false) {
$cur_str = trim($cur_str);
$cur_str_low = mb_strtolower($cur_str);
$cur_str_low = preg_replace('!\s+!', '', $cur_str_low);
$cur_str_low = str_replace('?', '', $cur_str_low);
$cur_str_low = str_replace(':', '-', $cur_str_low);
$cur_str_low = str_replace(',', '-', $cur_str_low);
$cur_str_low = str_replace('.', '-', $cur_str_low);
$cur_str_low = $index.'-'.$cur_str_low;
$cur_str_low = urlencode(str_replace(' ', '-', $cur_str_low)); 
echo $index.' '.$cur_str_low.'<br />';
```

Comment: Без скрипта с проблемой очень сложно понять в чём дело.

Comment: Добавил кусок кода. $index это id статьи, он добавляется в url для уникализации через дефис. $file это источник текстовых строк

Comment: Примеры проблемных строк тоже добавьте. И все другое необходимое тоже